# HMVC codeigniter ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello I have installed my `HMVC codeigniter` project on localhost, but I am getting `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. I searched many sources but could not get any results. Where could I be doing wrong?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaZoG.png)

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, Rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]` this is causing the redirects I believe. I see you have commented Rule `#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.` you need to put some condition before your rule, do you need www be added there? Kindly do add more details in your question for better understanding.

Comment: No, I don't want to add `www`. My goal is to make the files run on localhost. I closed it with `#` there.

Comment: Then, mention simple point, FROM which url TO which url you want to server in backend in your question for better understanding of question.

Comment: Why don't you just use what is available here: http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

Comment: You've commented out the condition, which makes it redirect _all_ requests, creating a redirect loop. If you don't want to redirect, comment out the last RewriteRule as well (since that's what actually does the redirecting.)